# How to import an [objective-c++] class which imports a [c++] class into an [objective-c] class?

Tags: c++, objective-c, import, include, objective-c++

I have 3 files.

```
// A.h/A.m, Objective-C.
#import "B.h"
@interface A
{
  B* b;
}
@end
// Uses instance method of B in implementation.



// B.h/B.mm, Objective-C++.
#import "C.h"
@interface B
{
  C c;  // c is declared without pointer.
}
@end
// Uses member methods of C in implementation.



// C.h/C.cpp, C++.
#include <Box2D/Box2D.h>  // C++ library.    
class   C
{
    private:
    b2World     world;
    b2Body*     ground;
    b2Body*     ball;

    public:

    PhysicsSimulator();
    ~PhysicsSimulator();

    void    setupWorld();
    void    cleanupWorld();

    void    tickWorld();
};
// One file of Box2D library include <cassert>
```

This makes compile-time error.

```
/Users/eonil/Work/Trials/Box2DTest/Library/Box2D/Common/b2Settings.h:22:10: fatal error: 'cassert' file not found [1]
```

It looks I have to do something special when importing Objective-C++ from Objective-C. But I can't figure out what it is. And I'm not sure even that is possible or not. What's that..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't include C.h in B.h. Rather say `struct C;`. This will allow you to forward declare the type in a way that is compatible with Objective-C. In the `mm` include `C.h`.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I have mistake on some important point. `c` in `B` is declared without pointer. I modified question.

Comment: You can't do that in plain Objective-C. Everything has to be Objective-C++ if you just want to drop a C++ class as a member in your Obj-C class.